# Getting Sentences On The Webpage After Opening The Link

Tags: php, html

How can I search for a specific sentence on a website page from a link in PHP

I have this link (https://www.tokopedia.com/maybelline/maybelline-superstay-vinyl-ink-liquid-lipstick-unrivale) and if I open it it will appear as below, and I want to check if the link has words like the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpvnO.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Asking for an "how-to" is out of scope on SO.  You are expected to do research and ask a specific question.